# Eclipse CDT Toolchain - Tool that just calls JAVA code?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have created my own custom toolchain plugin for CDT, and it works pretty well. However there is one piece that I cannt figure out.

**Goal**

Create a Tool which calls a JAVA class, instead of sending a command line argument.

At first I mulled over the 'CustomBuildStep' option for the Tool plugin element, but that is not the solution. How can you do this?

**Hello World Request**

Here's a simple one - At the completion of the CDT-Managed Build (e.g. the make call completes), I would like to pop a message box that says 'Hooray!'.

**Current Workaround**

Currently I end up just doing

```
java -cp "some_obtuse_path_into_plugins_dir" MyClass.doPopup
```

This is a gnarly console output, and a total hack in my opinion.

Thoughts?

Here is a useful contextual answer (that doesn't answer my question, but may point to 'sorry, can't do that):

- [Stack Overflow: Eclipse-CDT: Whats the best way to add a custom build step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098723/eclipse-cdt-whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-custom-build-step)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered creating a new Nature for your project: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_natures.htm ? Then you can define your own builder to call the particular code you want.

I don't know how this would fit in your workflow, but it might a solution.

Comment: interesting, although I want to stick with the Eclipse CDT extension (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.buildDefinitions) & its toolChain extension. I don't see a clear way to extend/modify that with a Nature extension. thoughts?

Comment: The basic idea would be to create custom builder that would execute your java code. [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_builders.htm) is an example on how to do that.

To the best of my knowledge the CDT Managed Build is designed to work by calling outside executables, and that is the way I have used it before. If you want custom java code, then the Managed Build is not the right tool.

Comment: Whether you would like to add a nature, or not, depends on your situation. The more custom the build process, the better it is to add a nature.

In my experience, I have used a nature since it makes it clear that there is a custom step involved. But I can't really say what way is better.

Comment: I marked this as answer because as I see it this is the only option. I won't be using it however X(. If I find a hack-workaround and implement, I'll post that here. thx for the help.